# This keyword in function call

Tags: javascript, this

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  sayHello() {
    alert(this.name);
  },
  sayGoodBye() {
    alert("good bye " + this.name);
  }
};

(user.name === "John" ? user.sayHello : user.sayGoodBye)();
```

Or how come `(user.sayHello)();` works if it is not within the condition. That is the ternary operator expression?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, even after fixing the missing semicolon - `this` always refers to `window` inside the functions, the result is incorrect regardless of condition

Comment: It is working now after editing it. But the question is still why?

Comment: `this.name` here will always refer to `window.name` in this example

Comment: copy the code and change the condition to false and it works correctly. And by the way, running this code gave out gibberish result.

Comment: I know about the window object and I did try to search before posting the question.

the main point of the question is why this (user.name === "John" ? user.sayHello : user.sayGoodBye)(); won't work but (user.sayGoodBye)(); work?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer . `this.name` doesnt work in object as `this` will resolves the scope and look for `name` variable outside the `user` object .

```
var user = {
  name: "John",
  sayHello() {
    console.log("Say hello" , this.name);
    alert(user.name);
  },
  sayGoodBye() {
    alert("good bye " + user.name);
  }
};

(user.name === "John" ? user.sayHello : user.sayGoodBye)();
```

Try out this code . It works fine .

Comment: but how come if the condition is false, it works correctly? I do not understand. the code still uses let instead of var.

Comment: i couldn't understand your comment . Will you please explain it properly ? @kenryuakuma

Comment: Sorry mistake. I meant why if we just call (user.sayHello)(); then it works? but not within the ternary operator expression?

Comment: It is working in ternary operater . @kenyauakuma

Answer (score 0):

Why your code is not working?
**Because this will refer to the window object. If you will call the function on user object then this in function will refer to user object**

Try this :

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello:",this.name);
  },
  sayGoodBye() {
    console.log("good bye " + this.name);
  }
};

(user.name === "John1" ? user.sayHello() : user.sayGoodBye());
(user.name === "John" ? user.sayHello() : user.sayGoodBye());
```

The second **alternative** could be to bind the function manually like this:

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello:",this.name);
  },
  sayGoodBye() {
    console.log("good bye " + this.name);
  }
};

// Manual this binding
user.sayHello = user.sayHello.bind(user);
user.sayGoodBye = user.sayGoodBye.bind(user);

(user.name === "John1" ? user.sayHello : user.sayGoodBye)();
(user.name === "John" ? user.sayHello : user.sayGoodBye)();
```

Comment: the trick is how the this keyword is resolved with the code I posted. The code snippet was copied from an article written by a senior javascript developer. 

If the condition is false, the code works correctly without having to modify it.

Comment: For me, this is not working when condition is false. Check this repl - https://repl.it/repls/BlindAnxiousMonad

Comment: @kenryuakuma Please re-check the result, the context is always `window`. How old is the article, or can you provide a link to it?

Comment: It works in jsfiddle. But anyway, why does it work if we just put (user.sayHello)();? That is why I do not understand.

Comment: @ManishMenaria Notice, that in the first snippet you're using ternary operator in a way it should not be used (just because of side effects).

Answer (score 0):

> Internals: Reference Type In-depth language feature

This section covers an advanced topic, to understand certain edge-cases better.

If you want to go on faster, it can be skipped or postponed.

An intricate method call can lose this, for instance:

```
let user = {
  name: "John",
  hi() { alert(this.name); },
  bye() { alert("Bye"); }
};

user.hi(); // John (the simple call works)

// now let's call user.hi or user.bye depending on the name
(user.name == "John" ? user.hi : user.bye)(); // Error!
```

On the last line there is a conditional operator that chooses either user.hi or user.bye. In this case the result is user.hi.

Then the method is immediately called with parentheses (). But it doesn’t work correctly!

As you can see, the call results in an error, because the value of "this" inside the call becomes undefined.

This works (object dot method):

```
user.hi();
```

This doesn’t (evaluated method):

```
(user.name == "John" ? user.hi : user.bye)(); // Error!
```

Why? If we want to understand why it happens, let’s get under the hood of how obj.method() call works.

Looking closely, we may notice two operations in obj.method() statement:

```
First, the dot '.' retrieves the property obj.method.
Then parentheses () execute it.
```

So, how does the information about this get passed from the first part to the second one?

If we put these operations on separate lines, then this will be lost for sure:

```
let user = {
  name: "John",
  hi() { alert(this.name); }
}

// split getting and calling the method in two lines
let hi = user.hi;
hi(); // Error, because this is undefined
```

Here `hi = user.hi` puts the function into the variable, and then on the last line it is completely standalone, and so there’s no this.

To make `user.hi()` calls work, JavaScript uses a trick – the dot '.' returns not a function, but a value of the special Reference Type.

The Reference Type is a “specification type”. We can’t explicitly use it, but it is used internally by the language.

The value of Reference Type is a three-value combination (base, name, strict), where:

base is the object.
name is the property name.
strict is true if use strict is in effect.

The result of a property access user.hi is not a function, but a value of Reference Type. For user.hi in strict mode it is:

```
// Reference Type value
(user, "hi", true)
```

When parentheses () are called on the Reference Type, they receive the full information about the object and its method, and can set the right this (=user in this case).

Reference type is a special “intermediary” internal type, with the purpose to pass information from dot . to calling parentheses ().

Any other operation like assignment `hi = user.hi` discards the reference type as a whole, takes the value of `user.hi` (a function) and passes it on. So any further operation “loses” this.

So, as the result, the value of this is only passed the right way if the function is called directly using a dot obj.method() or square brackets obj'method' syntax (they do the same here).

Comment: I think you should fix the misleading statement in the question ("_If the condition is false, the code works normally because user.sayGoodBye(); is invoked and this is passed in_") in order to avoid more down votes. As it is, the issue is not reproducible. Btw. the result is not gibberish, "sif5" is the name of `window` where the Stack Snippet is placed.